# using touch to activate an event

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game based off of [this](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/) but trying to implement it to work on a Touch device. the code for if they are touching is still the same;

```
if (
    reggie.x <= (monster.x + 32)
    && ball.x <= (reggie.x + 32)
    && reggie.y <= (monster.y + 32)
    && ball.y <= (reggie.y + 32)
) {
    ++ballsCollected;
    reset();
}
```

to make it to where you do not need a directional pad on a touch device I am trying to figure out how to make it where if you clicked on ball it then adds one to ballsCollected. I've looked at using Touch Events but i am not sure how I would go about making it work.

if there is a way to move reggie by dragging him with your fingers to make the two objects connect and still add one that would be cool and add a bit of a challenge.

any help or point in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with "where if you clicked on ball"? Please show us your event handler code, not the object collision code if your question is not about that.

Comment: Uh, you really should not have committed your code as a note on a commit...

Comment: Sorry, my brain shut off about an hour ago.
https://github.com/ZombiEquinox/Javascript-code/blob/master/.gitignore
This is the whole code.

Comment: Yes, that's true. A .gitignore file should not contain JS code, submit a .js file instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

> any help or point in the right direction would be helpful

There are many references out on the web. Have a look at

- [W3 spec draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/)
- [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events)
- [html5rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/)
- quriksmode.org: [The touch action](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/02/the_touch_actio.html) / [Do we need touch events?](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/02/do_we_need_touc.html)
- [jQuery mobile's events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

use touchmove event instead of keydown if you want to use touch device.

```
     $("#game-container").bind("touchmove", function (event) {

          reggie.x = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
          reggie.y = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;

          if (
      reggie.x <= (monster.x + 32)
      && monster.x <= (reggie.x + 32)
      && reggie.y <= (monster.y + 32)
      && monster.y <= (reggie.y + 32)
          ) {
              ++monstersCaught;
          reset();
        }

      });
```